# Optimaze php 'upload_max_filesize' and 'post_max_size' setting

Tags: php, file-upload, php-ini

I set the "`upload_max_filesize=1024M`" and "`post_max_size=1024M`" in php.ini.

I found a problem when I upload a big size file (2048M) via web browser.

The file was still uploading, while I can see the upload progress number and got PHP message in apache server log (/var/log/apache) immediately that like this:

```
"PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 2147483647 bytes exceeds the limit of 1073741824 bytes"
```

Finally the upload job would failed because the size of file is larger than the upload_max_filesize (2048M > 1024M)

How I can refuse the upload job as soon as possible while I deed know the size is larger than upload_max_filesize?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514166/check-file-size-before-upload

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190934/getting-upload-file-size-before-upload

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112575/client-checking-file-size-using-html5

Comment: hmm.. should I close is as duplicate or one click on google? :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via HTML5.

```
<input type="file" id="myFile" />


var size = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0].size;
```